# Drag and Drop in CKeditor (AngularJs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, ckeditor

So I am using the Ckeditor wrapped in a directive in Angularjs:

```
.directive('htmlEditor', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            var ele = element[0];

            var init = function () {
                if (!window.CKEDITOR || !window.ckinited) {
                    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
                    scriptTag.onload = handleScriptLoad;
                    scriptTag.src = '//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.8/full/ckeditor.js';
                    $window.document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);

                    window.ckinited = true;
                } else {
                    handleScriptLoad();
                }
            };

            var handleScriptLoad = function () {
                var config = {
                    allowedContent: true,

                    toolbar: [
                        {name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
                        {name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent']},
                        {name: 'text-align', items: ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock']},
                        {name: 'styles', items: ['Font', 'FontSize']},
                        {name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
                        {name: 'tools', items: ['Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Maximize']},
                    ]
                };

                ele.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
                var editor = window.CKEDITOR.replace(ele, config);

                editor.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);

                editor.on('change', function (evt) {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(evt.editor.getData());
                });

                editor.on( 'dragstart', function( evt ) {
                    console.log("something");
                });

                editor.on( 'dragenter', function( evt ) {
                    console.log("something");
                });

                editor.on( 'dragover', function( evt ) {
                    console.log("something");
                });

                ngModel.$render = function () {
                    editor.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
                };
            };

            init();
        }
    };
});
```

I am trying to use the ckeditor drag and drop feature work with this angular drag and drop module that I am using which can be found here: https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop . However, every time I drag a draggable object over the text area of the text editor none of the events 'dragenter' or 'dragover' fire up. How do I make this work? If someone could give me an example on how to drag and drop in the text area of the ckeditor and display it that would be great.